# Is there any English version of p transfer theorem of Wielandt?

Tags: reference-request, finite-groups, p-groups

I want to read a proof of the following theorem of Wielandt,

**Theorem:** Let $G$ be a finite group and let $P\in Syl_p(G)$ such that $P$ is regular. Then $N_G(P)$ controls $p$-transfer.

I found a proof of this theorem, but it is written in German (which I can not speak). Is there any English version of this proof?

It is also welcome to give a proof here.

**Note:** the proof is in Endliche Gruppen I" by Bertram and Huppert, chapter IV, part 8 (page 447)

Comment: We have plenty of German users, so an option may be to copy/paste taxing parts of the proof here, and ask for a translation. Of course, as may be likely, if the proof is split over several lemmas, corollaries and propositions that may not be feasible. Have you looked at Isaacs' book? At least in the early chapters he covers Wielandt's contributions quite well. This result is, alas, beyond me :-(

Comment: Alternatively, where did you come across the German proof? Others may also have access to it and be able to translate it (I can usually handle group theory in German for example).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: In the book "Endliche Gruppen I" by  Bertram,Huppert, cheapter IV, part 8 (page 447)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: In Isaac's book, there is a cheapter "More on transfer". In this cheaper, Yoshida's theorem is proved which is a generalization of Wielandt theorem. Original proof of Yoshida's theorem uses Character theory. Isaac proved a transfer version of "Mackey Theorem". Then proof proceed over many steps. Even if I can verify the proof, I do not "really undertstand" it. That is why I want to read the proof of Wielandt theorem.

Comment: I will take a look in Huppert if I get some time. It is usually readable, though not easily, due to the heavy notation (lots of Gothic letters) plus my limited German abilities.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Thank you very much :)

Comment: You could try to take a look at Theorem 14.4.2 in Marshall Hall's group theory book. Hall says that it improves a result of Wielandt, but I am not sure how to get the theorem you want as a corollary. It seems at least show that $N_G(\Omega_1(P))$  controls $p$-transfer if $P$ is a regular Sylow $p$-subgroup.

Comment: @MikkoKorhonen: Thank you very much, I will check it :)